# Does Steven ever use the TV after being grounded?

Tags: steven-universe

At the end of the episode "[Fusion Cuisine](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_Cuisine)" (S1 Ep32) after Steven tried to run away from home with Connie, the gems gave Steven a harsh punishment.

> Pearl: Steven, you are in very big trouble, and we have no choice but
> to punish you.
>
> Garnet: No dinner for 1,000 years.
>
> Steven: 1,000?
>
> Pearl: We would never starve you, **but you will lose your TV privileges... for 1,000 years.**
>
> Steven: No! The midseason pre-finale of "Under the Knife"! How can you do this to me?! *cries slightly*

<sub>["Fusion Cuisine" Transcript from Steven Universe Wiki](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_Cuisine/Transcript)</sub>

Does this punishment stick? Has Steven ever watched TV after being grounded?

Comment: Note that Steven was un-grounded at the end of "Joy Ride" (S02E02).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Steven's punishment only lasts for twenty episodes, with Garnet rescinding it at the end of "Joy Ride" (S02E02).  In that time, it is mentioned or violated in the following episodes:

- "Lion 3: Straight to Video" (S01E35): Steven sneaks out of his room to the Big Donut in order to watch the video tape Rose left for him
- "Horror Club" (S01E41): Steven sits behind Ronaldo's couch to "watch" *Evil Bear 2*
- "Maximum Capacity" (S01E43):

  > Greg: So books are cool again?
  >   Steven: Yeah!  Ever since you guys grounded me from TV for a thousand years.
  >   Greg: We did what now?

  Steven also points out that he's still grounded when Greg starts to play the *Li'l Butler* tapes, and he continues to honor that, lapsing only briefly.
- "The Message" (S01E46) — Steven, Greg, and the Gems view Lapis' warning message on a TV together

Since "Joy Ride", Steven has returned to watching television, including *Crying Breakfast Friends* in "Cry for Help", *Camp Pining Hearts* in "Log Date 7 15 2", and *Lonely Blade* in "Bismuth", among other instances.

Comment: Note that neither Rose's tape nor Lapis' warning message would truly seem to qualify as "watching television" even though a television was involved. Watching a movie on video could also be debatable, although it's utterly in character for Steven to have forgotten about the grounding due to his excitement at doing something with his friends. And self-enforcing after watching a bit of the *Li'l Butler* marathon; well, there were two parental figures with him; it may have taken a little bit to realize that Greg didn't know, and Amethyst would tend to encourage breaking the rule.

Answer (score 1):

#### Strangely enough, no television is mentioned again until Steven goes to the lighthouse to watch scary movies with Ronaldo, Lars, and Sadie in the episode "Horror Club" (S1:E41).

Despite the Gem's claim of preventing Steven from watching television for a thousand years, it is safe to assume knowing how much Steven enjoys his [**television**](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven%27s_TV), especially "[**Crying Breakfast Friends**](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Crying_Breakfast_Friends!)" and "Lonely Blade" I doubt seriously if Garnet would carry through on their threat.

The fact of the matter was the Gems were trying to show Connie's parents they could be as strict and guideline-oriented as the Maheswarans were. They are, but in different ways. Blocking television isn't one of them.